# Bootstrap modal does not showing information

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have entered an internship for 6 month and I'm currently developing a web system using Bootstrap modal. I am experiencing an issue where my modal view is failing to show any information. There are no errors in the scripting but I do not know how to fix it. Its just blank. Any suggestion?

This is modal view for staff detail which is showing no information:

[image]

Below is the code from the two of files that are  being used to show the modal view.

**index.html**

```
<?php  
//index.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user ORDER BY user_id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 ?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
 <head>  
  <title>ADD NEW USER</title>  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
 </head>  
 <body>  
  <br /><br />  
  <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
   <h3 align="center">Admin Log Site </h3>  
   <br />  
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <div align="right">
     <button type="button" name="age" id="age" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_data_Modal" class="btn btn-warning">Add New User</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="employee_table">
     <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
       <th width="70%">Staff Name</th>  
       <th width="30%">View</th>
      </tr>
      <?php
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      ?>
      <tr>
       <td><?php echo $row["uname"]; ?></td>
       <td><input type="button" name="view" value="view" id="<?php echo $row["user_id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>  
  </div>
 </body>  
</html>  

<!-- modal insert division -->

<div id="add_data_Modal" class="modal fade">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">ADMIN SITE</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <form method="post" id="insert_form">
     <label>Enter Staff Username</label>
     <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" class="form-control" />
     <br />
     <label>Enter Staff ID</label>
     <input type="text" name="staff_number" id="staff_number" class="form-control"  />
     <br />
     <label>Staff Roles</label>
     <select name="staff_role" id="staff_role" class="form-control">
      <option value="Administration">Administration</option>  
      <option value="Project Manager">Project Manager</option>
      <option value="Staff">Staff</option>
     </select>
     <br />  
     <label>Password</label>
     <input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
     <br />  

     <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Add user" class="btn btn-success" />

    </form>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- modal view employer -->

<div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Staff Details</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail">

   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event){  
  event.preventDefault();  
  if($('#uname').val() == "")  
  {  
   alert("Name is required");  
  }  
  else if($('#staff_number').val() == "")  
  {  
   alert("Staff id is required");  
  }  
  else if($('#staff_role').val() == "")
  {  
   alert("Staff role is required");  
  }
  else if($('#password').val() == "")
  {  
   alert("password is required");  
  }


  else  
  {  
   $.ajax({  
    url:"insertdata.php",  
    method:"POST",  
    data:$('#insert_form').serialize(),  
    beforeSend:function(){  
     $('#insert').val("Inserting");  
    },  
    success:function(data){  
     $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
     $('#add_data_Modal').modal('hide');  
     $('#employee_table').html(data);  
    }  
   });  
  }  
 });




 $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(){
  //$('#dataModal').modal();
  var user_id = $(this).attr("user_id");
  $.ajax({
   url:"view.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{user_id:user_id},
   success:function(data){
    $('#employee_detail').html(data);
    $('#dataModal').modal('show');
   }
  });
 });
});  
 </script>
```

For the view inforamtion as follow.

**view.php**

```
    <?php  
//select.php  
if(isset($_POST["user_id"]))
{
 $output = '';
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE user_id = '".$_POST["user_id"]."'";
  //$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE user_id = '".$_POST["id"]."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 $output .= '  
      <div class="table-responsive">  
           <table class="table table-bordered">';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
     $output .= '
     <tr>  
            <td width="30%"><label> Staff Name</label></td>  
            <td width="70%">'.$row["uname"].'</td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td width="30%"><label>Staff Id</label></td>  
            <td width="70%">'.$row["staff_number"].'</td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td width="30%"><label>Staff Role</label></td>  
            <td width="70%">'.$row["staff_role"].'</td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <td width="30%"><label>password</label></td>  
            <td width="70%">'.$row["password"].'</td>  
        </tr>

     ';
    }
    $output .= '</table></div>';
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Not enough information here to answer/understand your question.

Comment: sorry for that. i have improve my question.

Comment: Thanks for the the new information. It helped me make sense of your question and edit your question to make your issue more clear.

Comment: can you change your success function to `success:function(data){
console.log(data);}` and post what is logged to the console.

Comment: sorry i not really understand your requested. it true that you want me change success:function(data){ console.log(data); } from this                                              
    success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $('#employee_detail').html(data);
    $('#view-dataModal').modal('show');
   }

Comment: Its okay. I figured it out, but yes. I suspected your AJAX call wasn't returning any HTML so I wanted to see what the results of the call. As suspected it wasn't returning anything because you were posting JSON and norm form data. Great job on the code. You had everything but that one little thing. Good luck with the internship.

Comment: Thanks for giving good comment. Really appreciate it, i will keep working on in with what you have give for a solution. Thanks again @AlexanderHiggins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `$.ajax` POST is sending `JSON` data but your `PHP` view is looking for items in `$_POST`.

To set `$_POST` values try this:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "view.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: "user_id="+user_id,
  success: function(data) {
    $('#employee_detail').html(data);
    $('#dataModal').modal('show');
  }
});
```

Note: Typically your input elements would be inside of a `<form>` tag. When they are you can use `$('#formid').serialize()` to convert your input elements into a string that you can pass to the ajax call as the data variable.

For example:

```
<form id="getUserDetails">
    <label for="user_id">A bar</label>
    <input id="user_id" name="user_id" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="PostThis();return false;
 />
</form>

var data = $('#getUserDetails').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "post",
    data: data ,
    success: function (response) {
       $('#employee_detail').html(response);
        $('#dataModal').modal('show');              

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }


});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explain. I will working on for this answer. thanks for the answer. it help me out to figure what is going wrong with my codes. thanks again @Alexander   . your response is good.